# CoreData - Crashing while saving

Tags: ios, core-data

So, this is my code:

ViewController 1 :

```
class ViewSet: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Label_1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Label_2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Text: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TestingCoreData")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        var results: NSArray = moc.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        if (results.count > 0) {
            var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
            Label_1.text = res.valueForKey("label_1") as? String
            Label_2.text = res.valueForKey("label_2") as? String
            Text.text = res.valueForKey("text") as? String

        } else {
            println("No results found")
        }


    }
}
```

ViewController 2:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Label_1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBOutlet var Label_1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addLabel_1(sender: AnyObject) {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var label1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TestingCoreData", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! NSManagedObjectContext
        label1.setValue("\(Label_1.text)", forKey: "label_1")

        moc.save(nil)
        println("Object saved")

        performSegueWithIdentifier("toLabel2", sender: self)

    }
}
```

ViewController 3:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Label_2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet var Label_2: UITextField!

    @IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var label2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TestingCoreData", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! NSManagedObjectContext
        label2.setValue("\(Label_2.text)", forKey: "label_2")

        moc.save(nil)
        println("Object saved")

        performSegueWithIdentifier("toText", sender: self)
    }
}
```

ViewController 4:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Text: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    @IBOutlet var Text: UITextView!

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var text = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TestingCoreData", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! NSManagedObjectContext
        text.setValue("\(Text.text)", forKey: "text")

        moc.save(nil)
        println("Object saved")

        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

}
```

I believe the code is very simple. I'm trying to learn my way through CoreData, but I can't seem to properly make it work.

It crashes here, when I press add to go to the 3rd view controller:

[image]

Can anyone help me? I'm new to this stuff! Thanks in advance

Comment: the method does not return a `NSManagedObjectContext` - it returns the class associated with "TestingCoreData". [-> docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:)

Comment: What should I do then? Sorry, new here =(

Comment: It should not return anything, it should save 'label1' into the managed object context. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: You should really read and follow a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)...

Comment: I was following a tutorial, that's why I got very confused. I was watching some lessons on youtube. Thanks for the link!